# Laravel MAMP Vhosts issue

Tags: laravel, mamp

Have the below config in vhosts.  Its always returns 500 error when i run it through MAMP.   Not sure what is wrong.  Stopped mamp  and ran it using valet.  laravel website runs successfully.  Permissions of bootstrap/cache and storage looks good.  Error logs are empty cant debug and debug setting set to true in .env file.  Only access log exists with 500 error.  Below is the vhosts config that i have for MAMP.  Other website in vhosts file work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName elearn.localhost
 ServerAlias elearn.localhost
 DocumentRoot "/Users/user1/code/elearn/public"
 ErrorLog "/Users/user1/logs/elearn.localhost-error_log"
 CustomLog "/Users/user1/logs/elearn.localhost-access_log" common
  <Directory "/Users/user1/code/elearn/public">
            DirectoryIndex index.php
   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
   Satisfy Any
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: can anyone help regarding this issue

Comment: Somewhere you should be able to access some error log with some details, since this is missing I am assuming the simple mistakes. Do you have a .htaccess file in your root folder to enable pretty URL's?

Comment: did you check laravel.log file ? If it is 500 error then it must log the error in storage/logs/laravel.log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Laravel are you using, if it is 5.6 make sure you're running PHP at at least 7.1 in MAMP - fallen foul of that myself a couple of times?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Your correct.  MAMP that i was using  was using PHP 7.0   Upgraded MAMP it works now

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty, checklist:

- is MAMP running under your user?
- make sure it's not permissions issues: commit, chmod 777 on project root, try again, if you still get 500 then it's ruled out
- stop valet, restart mamp, just to be sure no services parts are conflicting
- remove the vendor folder and composer install again, better be safe then sorry
- lastly, add a dd() to any route and test it, if you see the dd, means it's not related to mamp, valet or laravel, probably config, driver or other issues.